# Import Word table into Excel fails at GetObject

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am attempting to copy the table contents from word into excel. I have run the code below and it fails at GetObject UNLESS I have already opened the word doc in which case the code works fine. Is this a known issue with excel 2010? I have been unable to replicate the issue with Excel 365

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files,*.doc;*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
```

Revised code below (thanks to @Darren Bartrup-Cook), it runs through Create or Get object depending on the status of Word.
It still returns an **Automation error - The specific procedure could not be found** if I dont have the document already open

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim oWD_App As Object
    Dim oWD_Doc As Object
    Dim WordFilename As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = shImportBuffer
    Dim filter As String
    filter = "Word File Old (*.doc), *.doc," & _
    "Word File New (*.docx), *.docx,"

    'clear all of the content in the worksheet where the tables from the Word document are to be imported
    ws.Cells.ClearContents

    'displays a Browser that allows you to select the Word document that contains the table(s) to be imported into Excel
    WordFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , "Select Word file")
    If WordFilename = False Then Exit Sub

    'call function
    Set oWD_App = CreateWord

    With oWD_App
        Set oWD_Doc = .Documents.Open(WordFilename)
    End With

End Sub


Public Function CreateWord(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTempWD As Object
    'attempt GetObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTempWD = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    'if error then CreateObject rather than get
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTempWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If

    oTempWD.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateWord = oTempWD

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateWord."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: @Teamothy I have made changes to the code to account for the need for either Create or GetObject (see above) still receiving the error. As I mentioned, I used the same coding on a different machine running Win10 and Office 365 (rather than Win 7 and Office 2010 where the error occurs) and the previous version of the code works. Are there any known issues, work arounds with legacy excel?

Comment: On which line error occurs?

Comment: @Teamothy It is caught by the error handler, passed on from create object.

Comment: To narrow this down, please test a procedure that *only* does `CreateObject("Word.Application")` and see if that fails. Then try with `New Word.Application` and see if it fails. (Note: if either or both are successful you'll need to exit these through the Task Manager. Or declare a variable and clean-up) The error "The specific procedure could not be found" seems incorrect - please check the error. Searching "The **specified** procedure could not be found" turns up that this appears when you run this code from within the application that should be started, so: Is this code in Word or in Excel?

Comment: If neither of the suggestions works and the code is running in Excel, try **repairing Office**. It's possible that Word is not correctly registered as "Word.Application". Ah, and does this machine have multiple versions of Word/Office running in-parallel?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub Test()


Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer
Dim wkSht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.Tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
            'ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
            ' tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
            ' "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 1

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .Tables(tableStart)
            'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    wkSht.Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol

                With wkSht
                    .Range(.Cells(resultRow, 1), .Cells(resultRow, iCol)).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                End With

                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        'resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With


End Sub
```